# Failed to load xxx.component.html

Tags: angular

I'm facing a strange problem. 
As my module grow, I decided to create some subfolders and put in subfolders my components.

Here is my new structure :

```
claimfile/
    appendix-tabs/
        appendix-tabs.component.html
        appendix-tabs.component.ts
    quick-create/
        quick-create.component.html
        quick-create.component.ts
    claimfile.component.html
    claimfile.component.less
    claimfile.component.ts
    claimfile.module.ts
```

I use Webpack, and I specify all my styleUrls and templateUrl with relative paths. 
But now, I have this message :

```
zone.js?fad3:1274 GET http://192.168.33.10:7777/appendix-tabs.component.html 404 (Not Found)

Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load appendix-tabs.component.html ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load appendix-tabs.component.html 

undefinedError: Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load appendix-tabs.component.html(…)
```

It comes from the appendix-component which can't load his template :

**appendix-tabs.component.ts** :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'prop-appendix-tabs',
    templateUrl : './appendix-tabs.component.html'
})
export class AppendixTabsComponent {

    constructor() {}
}
```

To make it work, I have to specify the absolute path from my index.html :

```
templateUrl : 'app/claimfile/appendix-tabs/appendix-tabs.component.html'
```

Now, what I don't understand is that... it works perfectly for the quick-create component. And there's nothing different in the decorator :

**quick-create.component.ts** :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'prop-claimfile-quick-create',
    templateUrl: './quick-create.component.html'
})
export class QuickCreateComponent { }
```

It also work for the claimfile.component which is the bootstrap component of the module.

Another thing : when I set the absolute path and edit the template, the live-reloading doesn't trigger, it's like the file wasn't watched by Webpack.
Also, I don't use `moduleId: module.id` in the component because it seems to not work with Webpack

```
compiler.umd.js?9df7:13350 Uncaught TypeError: uri.match is not a function
```

Any ideas where it could come from ? It's not the first time it happens, I already experienced that kind of issue

Thx for your help

Comment: have you tried `templateUrl: 'quick-create.component.html'` ?

Comment: @SefaÜmitOray I think problem is with `appendix-tabs.component.html`.

Comment: same thing applies for that one too.

Comment: @SefaÜmitOray : I tried templateUrl: 'appendix-tabs.component.html' and it doesn't work, still the same 404 error. But for quick-create.component, it works both way.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, and it occurred suddenly, Have you solved, and detected the reason?

Comment: Have you solved?

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem.It just suddenly appeared with no explanation :(

I found that using require on the template fixed it immediately. No idea why....

```
@Component({
    selector: 'home', 
    template: require('./home.component.html')
})
export class HomeComponent {}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure this actually works? I get an error "template must be a string"

Comment: Angular has changed greatly since this answer appeared. It is highly likely to be wrong now.